# How to choose a JS Library?

Tags: library, javascript, jquery, react, angular

I am quite new to web programming and i want to learn something else besides vanilla JavaScript. I noticed that in my area that the most sought after is jQuery, then React, Angular and Vue. jQuery seems very tiresome and spaghetti-like, but again, it is the most popular. The other 3 seem cleaner and more tidy, and they are the main thing to learn in internships.

What are your opinions on this? Do you have any other recommendations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the question is off-topic as it is written now; this is not a discussion board about the merits of different tools. Please [edit] your question and write down all *your* (technical) requirements. Reading [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) may help.

Comment: what are you looking to achieve here? Are you learning for private projects, to contributing to open source, to land a job, something else?

Comment: i'm just starting out in this field and  there are many options out there. I just dont know which is the best one for a newbie like me. Im eager to learn but I want to learn what is actually useful in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: My JS skills are intermediate. This is my opinion:

jQuery is a simple single file that gives you browser-independence for (a) manipulating the DOM and (b) to perform AJAX requests. It gives you -without much effort- the ability to write such JS code that works on legacy browsers down to IE8 (if you need that).

Modern Javascript, as implementeded in current Browsers, gives you many of jQuery's features in  a similar, even better way, so you don't need jQuery as much as in previous years.

Besides, if you decide to use React, Angular or Vue, you probably don't need jQuery because it is just another dependency that makes everything less "clean".

For the other software (except Vue) you've mentioned, there's more to learn. You probably need a build-system and a more complex development environment.

React is an option if you want to write mobile apps in Javascript (via React-native).

Don't know much about Angular(s).

Vue used to be way less complex than React or Angular, can also be used as a single file but usually you need some add-ons. It gives you *reactivity*.

Comment: thank you so much! so, out of all  these four, which one would you recommend as a starting point?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Study some publications/courses about the [Javascript Language](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/preface.md) by Kyle Simpson (getify) first, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The frameworks you mentioned will bring you a lot of tools and support, which is important if you want to create professional web applications. jQuery is a bit different as you can pick what you need and leave the rest unused. This only will bring you some overhead.

If your target is small applications for internal use, maybe the "big" frameworks bring too much headaches to learn. And they will force you to use their special workflow, you cannot easily decide to use a bit of angular here, some React there and on top some VUE.

Maybe you give the [Document Makeup Library (DML)](https://github/efpage/DML) a try, which is not so intrusive. You can create full featured web pages with DML or use only parts where appropriate. Or you can create Webcomponents and use plain HTML.

Comment: Thx for the corrections!